# How to identify the index that corresponds to a particular ordering of N boolean values in an array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing, boolean, binary-data

Suppose I perform `n=3` coin-flips, for which each `sub_state=True` if the flip returns tails (T) or `sub_state=False` if the flip returns heads (H). Then, there are `2 ** 3 = 8` possible `states` since each `sub_state` can only take on `2` values (`True` or `False`) and there are `3` coin-flip trials.

The `8` states enumerated arbitrarily are:

1. T-T-T
2. H-T-T
3. T-H-T
4. T-T-H
5. H-H-T
6. H-T-H
7. T-H-H
8. H-H-H

Knowing the particular series of coin-flip trials (ie, H-T-T) reveals which state is currently occupied.

I would like to write a function; this function takes `sub_states` as input, where `sub_states` is a boolean array of size `n` (ie, `[False, True, True]` corresponding to H-T-T), and returns as output the corresponding index (ie, `2 - 1 = 1`).

I am not sure how to approach this problem. I think there may be way to do this using binary numbers `01` that correspond to each of the `2**n` states, or maybe a simpler way with `numpy` magic and `itertools`. What are some approaches or methods I can use to solve this problem?

```
import numpy as np

def get_state_index(sub_states):
    """
    Suppose sub_states is a list of
    boolean values of length 3. Then,
    there are 2 ** 3 = 8 possible states.

    sub_states = [False, True, True]
    ==> state_index = 1

        state 0:
            coin-flips: T-T-T
            sub-states: [True, True, True]

        state 1:
            coin-flips: H-T-T
            sub-states: [False, True, True]

        state 2:
            coin-flips: T-H-T
            sub-states: [True, False, True]

        state 3:
            coin-flips: T-T-H
            sub-states: [True, True, False]

        state 4:
            coin-flips: H-H-T
            sub-states: [False, False, True]

        state 5:
            coin-flips: H-T-H
            sub-states: [False, True, False]

        state 6:
            coin-flips: T-H-H
            sub-states: [True, False, False]

        state 7:
            coin-flips: H-H-H
            sub-states: [False, False, False]
    """
    raise ValueError("not yet implemented")
    state_index = ...
    return state_index

if __name__ == '__main__':

    ## initialize sub-states
    sub_states = np.full(
        3,
        False,
        dtype=bool)
    sub_states[1] = True
    sub_states[2] = True

    ## initialize states
    states = np.full(
        2 ** sub_states.size, # len([True, False]) == 2
        False,
        dtype=bool)
    ##
    # i = get_state_index(sub_states)
    ##
    states[i] = True
    print(states)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little less arbitrary ordering:

```
state_index = sum(state * 2 ** pos for pos, state in enumerate(sub_states))
```

every `False` counts as a zero, every `True` as a one. Multiply them with their positional values in binary representation, and sum the result, effectively interpreting them as a binary number (though with least-significant-bit-first). For example, `[False, False, True]` is `0*1 + 0*2 + 1*4`, equivalent to `0b100`. You could also get the same result by converting each element into a string `0` or `1`, smushing them together and then interpreting them as a binary:

```
state_index = int(''.join(str(int(state)) for state in reversed(sub_states)), 2)
```

(`reversed` is there just to get the same result as above, with LSB-first. If you prefer MSB-first, remove `reversed` from this snippet, or add it into the previous one.)

Comment: I do not have sufficient reputation to upvote this answer, but this was very helpful - thank you!